# MFC ODBC SQLConfigDataSource() Unhandled Exception

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, mfc, odbc

I'm trying to update an old c++ MFC program and SQLConfigDataSource is causing an unhandled exception when I try to create a DSN. The error message says:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC97D89129 (KernelBase.dll):
>   0x0000087A (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF887A0001, 0x0000000000000053)

The code runs correctly and functions as it should, but I can't seem to get rid of this error.

```
int mlen;
char* szDesc = new char[256];
sprintf_s(szDesc, 256, "DSN=%s?DBQ=%s?FIL=MicrosoftAccess?",
    IV_DATABASE_NAME, // DSN name
    sDBPath); // full file name for accdb file

mlen = strlen(szDesc);
for (int i = 0; i < mlen; i++) {
    if (szDesc[i] == '?')
        szDesc[i] = '\0';
}

SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_ADD_DSN,
    "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)",
    (LPCSTR)szDesc);

delete szDesc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was occurring when Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable was installed. I installed the 2010 Redistributable and it runs perfectly without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for `SQLConfigDataSource` are ill formed. See:

[SQLConfigDataSource Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconfigdatasource-function?view=sql-server-2017)

And:

[ConfigDSN Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/configdsn-function?view=sql-server-2017)

> Each pair is terminated with a null byte, and the entire list is
>   terminated with a null byte. (That is, two null bytes mark the end of
>   the list.)

I've had this working for over a decade now and call it like:

```
if( ! bOk )//failed to open the default database for lack of DSN
{
    TRACE("Could not find DSN\n");

    BOOL ret= SQLConfigDataSource(
        NULL,
        ODBC_ADD_DSN,
        (LPSTR) "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)\0",
        (LPSTR) "DSN=MS Access Database\0"
        "Description=MS Access Database\0"
        );
    if( ! ret )
    {
        AfxMessageBox( _T("The 'Data Source Name' failed to install\nPlease call My Company\n800-555-5555") );
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Note that the first two extra nulls are redundant, but they do no harm. But the last line follows the two null, end of list, rule.

```
"Description=MS Access Database\0"
```

You should be checking the return value of `SQLConfigDataSource`. And you can call `SQLInstallerError` as described in Diagnostics. Also, the comments state that the keywords and values should not contain `?`.